# Is there a way to determine whether the data has been received in a TCP Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

does any of you know if there is a way to tell whether or not the data sent through a Java TCP Socket has been received?

The TCP protocol should store the last acked byte somewhere, but I don't know if this information is available from the Java Socket.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't know that in Java, and being able to see the last acked tcp message wouldn't help, since what you write to the socket can be sent in one or more messages/packages.

You need to implement an application protocol where the receiver sends ack.

Comment: Well that's unconvenient. What's wrong about the last acked byte? If I monitor the data sent through the stream and I know the last acked byte I know that the data has arrived (independently from the number of packets needed). Implementing an application protocol adds too much overhead and unfortunately I can't afford it in my application.

Comment: Huh? Can't implement an application protocol? What are you sending? Have have never seen anyone send data without having an application protocol, even if it's a simple one.

Comment: The ack could be a single short message, e.g. “OK _#bytes_ received”.

Comment: BTW, I can't find where in the POSIX socket API you'd get the ID of the last packet transferred under the covers with a TCP socket. TCP deliberately hides that info from you…